# Finding the covariance and correlation of two random variables

Tags: statistics, covariance, correlation, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable that has a standard uniform distribution $U(0,1)$, let $Y = X^k$, $k > 0$. I have performed the random variable transformation receiving $g(y) = \frac{1}{k}y^{\frac{1}{k}-1}$. I have also managed to calculate $\sigma_X = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$, $\sigma_Y = \frac{k}{\sqrt{2k+1}(k+1)}$. I know that $cov(X,Y) = \mathsf E[XY] - \mathsf E[X]\mathsf E[Y]$. How can I find the $E(XY)$?

Comment: Using $XY=X^{k+1}$?

Comment: how could I have not thought about it.. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751719/expected-value-of-xn-for-normal-distribution

Comment: Note $E[X^n]=\frac1{n+1}$ so repeated use of this with different $n$ will give the various raw moments

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remember what it is $Y$.

$$
Cov(X,Y) = Cov(X,X^k)= E(XX^k) - E(X)E(X^k)  =E(X^{k+1}) - E(X)E(X^k) 
$$
and apply what they suggest in comments